# increment variable AFTER each foreach loop

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, auto-increment

I have a for each loop for importing some csv data. i need to increase $i after the whole loop runs on each ROW of the data.

Data going, simple  9 columns and the test file is only 2 rows, but the prod file is 500 rows

```
ID,LastName,FirstName,Add1,City,State,__ZipCode__,Phone,Email
11,lastnamevalue,firstnamevalue,addressvalue,cityvalue,MA,zip,6phone,email value
11,lastnamevalue2,firstnamevalue2,addressvalue2,cityvalue2,MA,zip2,6phone2,email value2
```

Loop info

```
$i=0; 
foreach ( $meta as $key => $value) {

     // If custom filed name is "textfield"
    if ($key == 'FirstName') {
        $meta_array[0]['members_'.$i.'_first_name'] = $value;
        $meta_array[1]['_members_'.$i.'_first_name'] = 'field_53eac4161a811';

    } elseif ($key == 'LastName') {
        $meta_array[0]['members_'.$i.'_last_name'] = $value;
        $meta_array[1]['_members_'.$i.'_last_name'] = 'field_53eac4291a812';

    } elseif ($key == 'Add1') {
        $meta_array[0]['members_'.$i.'_street'] = $value;
        $meta_array[1]['_members_'.$i.'_street'] = 'field_53eb96fc5d7da';

    } elseif ($key == 'City') {
        $meta_array[0]['members_'.$i.'_city'] = $value;
        $meta_array[1]['_members_'.$i.'_city'] = 'field_53eb97335d7dc';

    } elseif ($key == 'State') {
        $meta_array[0]['members_'.$i.'_state'] = $value;
        $meta_array[1]['_members_'.$i.'_state'] = 'field_5421e190161b0';

    } elseif ($key == '__ZipCode__') {
        $meta_array[0]['members_'.$i.'_zip_code'] = $value;
        $meta_array[1]['_members_'.$i.'_zip_code'] = 'field_5421e1acc0d65';

    } elseif ($key == 'Phone') {
        $meta_array[0]['members_'.$i.'_phone'] = $value;
        $meta_array[1]['_members_'.$i.'_phone'] = 'field_53ebb3419d355';

    } elseif ($key == 'Email') {
        $meta_array[0]['members_'.$i.'_email'] = $value;
        $meta_array[1]['_members_'.$i.'_email'] = 'field_5421e1b4c0d66';

    // Create array data to import to the Repeater Field
    }  else {
        $meta_array[$key] = $value;
    }

}
```

So i need $i to equal 0 fore each of those else if statements and then when it gets to the last email one, it needs to increase to 1 and stay 1 for each of the else if's again, until the last one and then increase to 2.. so on and so forth...

i think i need to count the else if or something, but i am terrible with loops and i can either get it to always be 0 or increase by 1 throughout every line so it ends up being firstname 1 firstname 2 etc.

UPDATE:  its for a wordpress plugin that imports csv data... the csv is set up as firstname lastname blah blah...   each value gets set as its actual value and then anotehr one gets set with that "field_53eac4161a811" or whatever each one its... so each elseif inputs two rows into the database. which is working fine..(the array comes out as all teh info matched up but the $i is either always 0 or increments for each key/value instead of only once per loop) . except it is overwriting the previous one because the $i variable is the only marker that changes for each csv row of data... not sure if that helps explain it at all.

below is what should come out... and it does, except when the file parses the next line of teh csv data it also come out with 0 0 0 0 0 0 instead of 1 1 1 1 1 1

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [members_0_last_name] => name value
        [members_0_first_name] => first name value
        [members_0_street] => street value
        [members_0_city] => city value
        [members_0_state] => state
        [members_0_zip_code] => zip
        [members_0_phone] => phone
        [members_0_email] => email
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [_members_0_last_name] => field_53eac4291a812
        [_members_0_first_name] => field_53eac4161a811
        [_members_0_street] => field_53eb96fc5d7da
        [_members_0_city] => field_53eb97335d7dc
        [_members_0_state] => field_5421e190161b0
        [_members_0_zip_code] => field_5421e1acc0d65
        [_members_0_phone] => field_53ebb3419d355
        [_members_0_email] => field_5421e1b4c0d66
    )

[field_53eac3eb1a810] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

Comment: initialize `$i` above outside the loop, then increment `$i++` before the ending bracket of the loop

Comment: @Ghost: I think he wants the loop to run with 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2... (8 times each number), but it's pretty vague and lots of details don't add up. OP, it would really really really help if you provided a sample of your input file.

Comment: that makes it add 1 to each of the $i variables ending up with the final one being 8   i need it to take each key value and have $i=0 then take each key value again and have all the $i's =1...

Comment: exactly amadan, i'm trying to help a friend out and i suck at loops. but i'm determined to get it lol

Comment: adding another dimension to the array rather than using variable variables would be my suggestion

Comment: @Dagon: Agreed. XY problem. I'd rather see the data and expected output, than figure out an answer for a question that the OP doesn't really need answered.

Comment: ok i added the array output that is coming out which is structured correctly, but when the next array gets parsed it is still all 0's OR if i put $i++ in, it ends up being 0-8  ...

Answer (score -1):

Won't you be hitting each of these if's only once? You could just put the increment inside your last else block.

Comment: This is correct, you can't have an array with repeating keys, this is a valid point. However, it belongs in comments.

Comment: i could loop it some other way probably, i just walked into it with a foreach loop, and was hoping it would work so i didn't have to change all sorts of other code...

Comment: and putting it inside the last else block didnt change anything... still output both as all 0's.